# How to create a regex pattern for a specific pattern in json file in scala

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to create a regex pattern to match a pattern in a Json file. Json file consists of the following kind of patterns -
Examples

- `“raw”: “”\\""`
- `“raw”: “true”`
- `“raw”: “”’""`

raw attribute can have any type of value between double quotes. I want to match all the patterns like this and replace it with “*” of the same length at that place.

I created a pattern `“”"“raw”:(".*")""".r` which works fine normally in editor but not in scala and it gives the complete string after raw.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing a part of a matched pattern with asterisks of the same legnth as the pattern part, you may use [a solution like](https://rextester.com/IOV51156)

```
val s = "Text here, \"raw\": \"Remove\" and here"
val rx = "(\"raw\":\\s*\")([^\"]+)(\")".r
val res = rx.replaceAllIn(s, m => m.group(1) + ("*" * m.group(2).length) + m.group(3))
println( res ) // => Text here, "raw": "******" and here
```

The regex is

```
(\"raw\":\\s*\")([^\"]+)(\")
|___ Group1 ___||_ G2 _||G3|
```

It matches and captures into Group 1 (thanks to the capturing parentheses) `"raw":` and then 0+ whitespaces (with `\s*`), then captures into Group 2 any one or more chars other than `"`, and then captures into Group 3 a double quotation mark.

With the help of `ReplaceAllIn`, you can pass the match data into a lambda expression where you may manipulate the match before the replacement occurs. So, `m` is the match object, `m.group(1)` is Group 1 value, `m.group(2).length` is the length of Group 2 value and `m.group(3)` here holds the `"` char, Group 3 value.

Comment: Thanks for informing me about this. I rarely post questions on stack overflow , therefore was not aware of it. I will take care of these things now onwards.